# Calculate the number of messages published to a Kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, promql, jmx-exporter

I am trying to get the number of new messages published to a particular Kafka topic over a period of time using the below PromQL.

But it doesn't look correct: the number returned by PromQL doesn't match with the actual number of messages published to the topic

```
sum(increase(kafka_server_brokertopicmetrics_messagesin_total{topic=~"topic1", instance=~"instance1"}[5m]))
```

Comment: Why do think you need `sum` in this query? And why are you using regex label selectors here, and not the simple `=`?

Comment: Transaction records are included in this metric.